# Filemaker - Authorization header 'Basic' invalid

Tags: php, api, filemaker

I installed the following vendor:
https://github.com/BlueFeatherGroup/eloquent-filemaker

and I'm trying to sync data from FileMaker to mysql via the API.

And my function when called the first time throws out this error, while the second time it passes properly.

This is my mistake:

```
   BlueFeather\EloquentFileMaker\Exceptions\FileMakerDataApiException

  Authorization header 'Basic' invalid.

  at vendor/bluefeather/eloquent-filemaker/src/Services/FileMakerConnection.php:167
    163▕                             // API token is expired. We should expire it in the cache so it isn't used again.
    164▕                             $this->forgetSessionToken();
    165▕                             return;
    166▕                         default:
    167▕                             throw new FileMakerDataApiException($message['message'], $code);
    168▕                     }
    169▕                 }
    170▕             }
    171▕         } else{

      +7 vendor frames
  8   app/Console/Commands/SyncFileMakerDB.php:93
      Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::__callStatic("count", [])
```

This is the connection in the .env file:

```
FM_DB_HOST = filemaker01.server
FM_DB_USERNAME = apirest
FM_DB_PASSWORD = vkjfkdjskfs
```

this is the database connection in database.php

```
'DATABASENAME' => [
    'driver' => 'filemaker',
    'host' => env ('FM_DB_HOST', ''),
    'database' => 'DATABASENAME',
    'username' => env ('FM_DB_USERNAME', ''),
    'password' => env ('FM_DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'prefix' => env ('FM_DB_PREFIX', ''),
    'version' => env ('FM_DB_VERSION', 'vLatest'),
    'protocol' => env ('FM_DB_PROTOCOL', 'https'),
    ],
```

DATABASENAME class

```
<? php

namespace App \ Models \ FileMaker \ DATABASENAME;

use App \ Traits \ FormatsAttributeNames;
use BlueFeather \ EloquentFileMaker \ Database \ Eloquent \ FMModel;
use Illuminate \ Database \ Eloquent \ Factories \ HasFactory;

class DATABASENAME extends FMModel
{
    use HasFactory;
    use FormatsAttributeNames;

    protected $ connection = 'DATABASENAME';
    protected $ layout = 'ApiLayout';

    protected $ fieldMapping = [
        'Article (1)' => 'Article',
        'Article2' => 'Article2',
        'BestellNr2' => 'Bestellnr_2',
    ];
}
and I have now created a command that synchronizes data from FileMaker to Mysql DB

protected $ signature = 'sync-filemaker-db {db}';

 public function handle ()
   {
       switch ($ this-> argument ('db')) {
           case 'DATABASENAME':
               $ this-> handleDATABASE ();
               break;
           default:
               $ this-> error ('No valid database provided');
               return 1;
       }

       return 0;
   }

   public static function> handleDATABASE ()
   {
       $ offset = 0;

       $ count = DATABASENAME :: count ();
       while ($ offset <$ count) {
           DATABASENAME :: offset ($ offset) -> get () -> each (function (DATABASENAME $ item) use (& $ offset) {
               $ recordId = (int) $ item-> getRecordId ();

               MYSQLTABLENAME :: updateOrCreate ([
                   'record_id' => $ recordId,
               ], DATABASENAME :: formatAttributeNames ($ item-> getAttributes ()));

               $ offset ++;
           });
       }
     dump ($ offset);
   }
```

and then I call my command:

```
php artisan sync-filemaker-db DATABASENAME
```

and then every time I first call the command php artisan sync-filemaker-db DATABASENAME this error pops up:

BlueFeather\EloquentFileMaker\Exceptions\FileMakerDataApiException

Authorization header 'Basic' invalid.

at C:\xampp\htdocs\enterprise-service-bus\vendor\bluefeather\eloquent-filemaker\src\Services\FileMakerConnection.php:167

163▕                             // API token is expired. We should expire it in the cache so it isn't used again.
164▕                             $this->forgetSessionToken();
165▕                             return;
166▕                         default:
"https://filemaker01.server/fmi/data/vLatest/databases/DATABASENAME/layouts/ApiLayout/records/", [])
And the second time I call her again, and so every next time she does everything.

Does the library take the Token and then use it, but the old one stays with her, I don't know what else could be the problem?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The error is that the Data API Token is invalid. You need to first connect and get a token.
Try using the login() function before making any calls.
https://github.com/BlueFeatherGroup/eloquent-filemaker/blob/95d4b788ac2b6fecc6aeba5ef531e5a9ddf90430/src/Services/FileMakerConnection.php#L52

Comment: Note that eloquent-filemaker caches session tokens, and assumes that the default DataAPI timeout is set to 15 minutes. If this is reduced, or if the DataAPI session is being closed another way, then it is possible that you will face authentication errors.

Comment: sorry but this is not the solution. Can you send me an example. Or how did you think to set up a connection via login?
This FileMakerConnection works by creating a new fetchNewSessionToken () or retaining it via login.

Comment: The issue is that FileMaker is receiving an invalid authentication token on the first call. You may need to contact eloquent-filemaker to see why the way you are using their solution is submitting an invalid authentication token.

Comment: I posted my Problem on https://github.com/BlueFeatherGroup/eloquent-filemaker/issues/21 , I hope someone sees it...

Comment: Try contacting them here: https://www.bluefeathergroup.com/contact/ or if that doesn't work try here: https://community.claris.com/en/s/

Comment: Glad to see you got it fixed - I saw the result on github